# Passing array of characters from FORTRAN DLL to Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dll, fortran, dllimport

I am trying to link a Fortran DLL to VBA.

I started by using Intel example (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/611723) and I am able to deal with all kind of data except array of strings.

It's important to notice how a single string of characters needs "ByVal" attributes, as can be stated also here (https://myengineeringworld.net/2014/03/calling-fortran-dll-from-excel-vba.html).

Here my example:

FORTRAN

```fortran
SUBROUTINE TESTARRAY (ELEMENTS, OUTARRAY) ! bind(c, name='TESTARRAY')
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, STDCALL, REFERENCE, ALIAS:"TESTARRAY" :: TESTARRAY

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER*4, INTENT(IN) :: ELEMENTS
CHARACTER*15, INTENT(OUT) :: OUTARRAY(ELEMENTS)
INTEGER*4:: I
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: ELEMENTS, OUTARRAY

DO I = 1,ELEMENTS
    WRITE(OUTARRAY(I),'(I3.3)') I
ENDDO

RETURN

END SUBROUTINE TESTARRAY
```

VBA

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Dim arraytest() As String * 15

Declare Sub TESTARRAY Lib "PATH\MYDLL.dll" (ELEMENTS As Long, ByVal OUTARRAY As String)

Public Function array_dll(iel As Long) As String

   ReDim arraytest(1 To iel)

    Call TESTARRAY(iel, arraytest(1))

    array_dll = Trim(arraytest(iel))

End Function
```

When I try to use inside an Excel sheet the function "array_dll" linked to a cell containing for example "5", I obtain an empty cell, and not "005" as expected.

How is the right method for dealing with that kind of data?

Comment: The usage is confusing. In your declaration, you have `OUTARRAY As String`, which isn't an array. You are actually assigning a single element of `arraytest` as a parameter to the `OUTARRAY`. Why are we talking about arrays but passing only a single string?

Comment: Furthermore, to rule out the possibility of incompatible string marshaling, you could change the signature to `ByRef OUTARRAY As Byte()`, which will take a byte array. You should use `Dim b() As Byte` and use that as the parameter. You can then assign the result to a string and examine the content. It might not be in Unicode (VBA `String` are always Unicode) in which case you need to use `StrConv` to change encoding.

Comment: I declare "OUTARRAY" as a string and assigning only the first element, by following the directions reported here (https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/283267) and here (https://myengineeringworld.net/2014/03/calling-fortran-dll-from-excel-vba.html).

Comment: Keeping in mind that I'm not familiar with FORTRAN, I'm seeing that it doesn't have a true `String` data type. Rather, it uses `CHARACTER*N`, which is essentially a byte array. However, in your VBA code, you have it defined as an array of fixed length strings. You don't need that. You need to keep in mind that `String` = `Byte()`, so `ByRef OutArray() As Byte` will work just as `ByVal OutArray As String` would. However, using a byte array means no encoding is assumed, so you would be ale to examine the content of the byte array and convert it (e.g. using `StrConv`) to be readable in VBA.

Comment: Furthermore, again because I'm unfamiliar with FORTRAN, we have `CHARACTER*15, INTENT(OUT) :: OUTARRAY(ELEMENTS)` and `ELEMENTS` is a parameter. Is that declaring a fixed-length string of 15 characters and then picking an element within that string? Or is that making an array of fixed-length strings? I probably would want to avoid dealing with an array of strings (e.g. an array of byte arrays) and focus on only one thing -- string/byte array until it's working.